# nvprof application not found

Tags: cuda, opencl, nvidia, profiler

I am trying to use Nvidia `nvprof` to profile my CUDA and OpenCL programs. However, whatever benchmark I choose, the only output is `======== Error: application not found.` I have tried both CUDA and OpenCL benchmarks, and recompiled them several times, but it seems helpless.

My CUDA version: 4.2

NVIDIA Driver version: 334.21

Comment: what is the exact nvprof command line you are using?

Comment: `nvprof ApplicationName`, no arguments

Comment: Are you sure you've added `nvprof` and the other CUDA binaries to your PATH?

Comment: Yes, because I can use `nvprof --version` to get the version information.

Comment: Is this on linux?  If so, you need to do `nvprof ./ApplicationName`, not `nvprof ApplicationName`

Comment: (and I don't know for sure that nvprof works with OpenCL, although it may)

Comment: @RobertCrovella -- Yes, it seems that `./` is the reason. I left out it because in AMD sprofile it is not necessary to do that. (Unfortunately nvprof can only work with CUDA)

Comment: so do you want to provide an answer?  You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different from AMD sprofile, `./` is needed before the application name on Linux.

So you can call the profiler with this command:
`nvprof ./ApplicationName`